# ¿Como convertir una variable de undefined a vacio

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente tengo la siguiente función donde obtengo ciertos valores.

```
$('#listado-sucursales').on('change', '.sucursal_correo', function (e) {
    console.log("Obteniendo sucursal");
    let sucursal_correos = $(this).closest('.tr_correos');
    let cod_agencia = sucursal_correos.find('.cod_agencia_correos').text();
    let nombre_agencia_correos = sucursal_correos.find('.nombre_agencia_correos').text();
    let canton_agencia_correos = sucursal_correos.find('.canton_agencia_correos').text() || '';
    let codprov_agencia_correos = sucursal_correos.find('.codprov_agencia_correos').text();
    let departamento_agencia_correos = sucursal_correos.find('.departamento_agencia_correos').text();
    let direccion_agencia_correos = sucursal_correos.find('.direccion_agencia_correos').text();
    let distrito_agencia_correos = sucursal_correos.find('.distrito_agencia_correos').text();
    let provincia_agencia_correos = sucursal_correos.find('.provincia_agencia_correos').text();

    let obj_sucursal_correos = {};

    obj_sucursal_correos.cod_agencia = cod_agencia;
    obj_sucursal_correos.nombre_agencia = nombre_agencia_correos;
    obj_sucursal_correos.canton_agencia_correos = canton_agencia_correos;
    obj_sucursal_correos.codprov_agencia_correos = codprov_agencia_correos;
    obj_sucursal_correos.departamento_agencia_correos = departamento_agencia_correos;
    obj_sucursal_correos.direccion_agencia_correos = direccion_agencia_correos;
    obj_sucursal_correos.distrito_agencia_correos = distrito_agencia_correos;
    obj_sucursal_correos.provincia_agencia_correos = provincia_agencia_correos;

    localStorage.setItem('json_sucursal_correo', JSON.stringify(obj_sucursal_correos));
    console.log(obj_sucursal_correos);
});
```

El problema que tengo es que en algunas variables se guarda "undefined", entonces si el caso es ese, debo convertir las variables a vacio ""
por ejemplo esta variable:

let canton_agencia_correos = sucursal_correos.find('.canton_agencia_correos').text() || '';

Si el valor `sucursal_correos.find('.canton_agencia_correos').text()` no existe o es undefined, debo guardar un vació ''.

pero tal situación no me funciona.

Al final obtengo un json de la siguiente forma:

```
    {"cod_agencia":"0001",
"nombre_agencia":"Sucursal San Pedro Sula",
"canton_agencia_correos":"undefined",
"codprov_agencia_correos":"undefined",
"departamento_agencia_correos":"undefined",
"direccion_agencia_correos":"undefined",
"distrito_agencia_correos":"undefined",
"provincia_agencia_correos":"undefined"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa un ternario para verificar que tu objeto no sea undefined, y si lo es asignarle vacío:

`obj_sucursal_correos.canton_agencia_correos = canton_agencia_correos === undefined ? '' : canton_agencia_correos ;`

```js
let mivar = undefined;
//let mivar = 2;
let mivar2= mivar === undefined? '<vacio>' : mivar
console.log(mivar2)
mivar = 2;
let mivar3= mivar === undefined? '<vacio>' : mivar
console.log(mivar3)
```

Comment: Lo realice como dijiste: obj_sucursal_correos.canton_agencia_correos = canton_agencia_correos === undefined ? '' : canton_agencia_correos ; pero no me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof(tu_variable) == 'undefined'){
    tu_variable = '';
}
```

O en un ternario como pones (siempre y cuando hayan sido previamente declaradas):

```
tu_variable = typeof(tu_variable) == 'undefined' ? '' : tu_variable;
```

Comment: Me gustaría añadir que esto es un ejemplo de *programación defensiva* : undefined no es una palabra reservada y nada impide que hagas `var undefined=1` dentro de una función, con lo que tu_variable === undefined podría dar resultados no deseados. Dependiendo del grado de *paranoia* de cada desarrollador podemos contentarnos con una comparación u otra.